# Count unique IDs that if and only if all related records meet criteria in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset where has three columns: ID, level and status. I want to add a measure which can count unique IDs as all of their status are completed. The level column is filter. Basically, it needs to check all records on selected levels under the ID and if and only if they are "completed" then the ID will counted 1. Otherwise, do nothing.
[image]

Examples:

1, if the filter has values: l1,l2,l3, the total complete is 1 as ID: 2 as it has three completes and others have at least one incomplete
2,  if the filter has values: l1, the total complete is 2 as ID:1, and 2 as they have completes at l1.